# Problem in ubuntu mobile contacts

Tags: ubuntu-touch

By mistake I delete the favorite group in contact,after that I can't reload it from my Google account again and it is not in the all contacts either.

Answer (score 3):

If it is in your online Google account but not on your phone, hive you physically forced the sync, by pressing the sync icon in your contacts? If so have you made sure that contacts is enabled in your Settings > Accounts for the account you wish to download from.

Comment: Currently the contacrs is not working like the calendar, which is more the pity. The calendar automatically syncs and does a fantastic job of it. However with the contacts you have to physically force the sync every time a change is made. Hopefully soon the contacts will be an auto sync.